# Polygon from shape extents in QGIS

Tags: qgis, extents

In QGIS 3.4 is there a tool similar to the Extract Layer Extent but instead of a bounding box, it creates polygons? I have groups of lines representing a network of roads and I want to show the missing sections but creating polygons around the groups. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

I realise using Minimum Bounding Geometry with convex hull and grouping by the attributes does what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The Minimum Bounding Geometry tool was nice, but it still created polygons far to greater in size than what I needed, plus it did not cater for donuts.

In the end, I just buffered the lines with a dissolve and this solved my particular issue.